# How Can I set Focus on a text Input Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am new to working with Modals.  I have 8 Modal setup and working except I need to set the focus to the Text Input when the Modal is displayed.  The is what I am using to show the individual Modal.

```
<div id="WestSide_Modal" class ="container">
    <div class ="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnWest">
            <div class="modal" id="viewWestSideModal" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Enter You Pin For West Bay</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div>
                                <label for="inputPinNumber">Pin Number</label>
                                <br />
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Pin #" type="password" id="txtWestPin" runat="server"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnWest" Text="Go" OnClick="OpenSelectedForm" />
                            <button class =" btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               
            </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have done some research and I am seeing I need to use a JQuery to accomplish this task below is what I am trying to use for that query.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#viewWestSideModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('#txtWestPin').focus();
});
```

});
The page builds and functions but the JQuery is not working so I don't get the focus set to my Input control. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The `'shown.bs.modal'` event isn't fired on the modal itself. You need to attach it to the document. No need to wrap it in `$(document).read()` and no need to use `find()` since you're using an id. This should do it:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#txtWestPin').focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I swapped out my Java code for yours but still did not get the focus.  I am not sure about your statement "You need to attach it to the document" Did I need to do something else other than changing the JavaScript.  sorry if that was a dumb question ,like I said I have never used the Modal  control

Comment: if you can reproduce the code in a jsfiddle i can debug it. if i can't reproduce the problem then i can't tell you what's wrong with it. this is javascript by the way. java has nothing to do with javascript. two entirely different languages they only share the first 4 letters of their name.